# React + Redux Server initialize with store and history

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I've the following app:

**Client**

> index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Root from "./containers/Root";
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
import { loginUserSuccess } from "./actions/auth";
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from "react-router-redux";

const target = document.getElementById("root");
const store = configureStore(browserHistory, window.__INITIAL_STATE__);
// Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

const node = (
    <Root store={store} history={history} />
);

let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
if (token !== null) {
    store.dispatch(loginUserSuccess(token));
}

ReactDOM.render(node, target);
```

> Root.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import AppRouter from "../routes/appRouter";

export default class Root extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <AppRouter history={this.props.history}>
                </AppRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }       
}
```

> AppRouter (routes/appRouter.js

```
import React from "react";
import routes from "./routes";
import { Router } from "react-router";

export default (
    <Router routes={routes} history={this.props.history}></Router>
)
```

> routes (routes/routes.js)

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router";
import { App } from "../containers";
import {HomeView, LoginView, ProtectedView, NotFoundView} from "../views";
import {requireAuthentication} from "../components/core/AuthenticatedComponent";

export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App} name="app" >
        <IndexRoute component={requireAuthentication(HomeView)}/>
        <Route path="login" component={LoginView}/>
        <Route path="protected" component={requireAuthentication(ProtectedView)}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundView} />
    </Route>
)
```

> requireAuthentication (/component/core/AuthenticatedComponent.js)

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { push } from "react-router-redux";

export function requireAuthentication(Component) {

    class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

        componentWillMount () {
            this.checkAuth(this.props.isAuthenticated);
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
            this.checkAuth(nextProps.isAuthenticated);
        }

        checkAuth (isAuthenticated) {
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                let redirectAfterLogin = this.props.location.pathname;
                this.props
                    .dispatch(push(`/login?next=${redirectAfterLogin}`));
            }
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.isAuthenticated === true
                        ? <Component {...this.props}/>
                        : null
                    }
                </div>
            )

        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        token: state.auth.token,
        userName: state.auth.userName,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent);

}
```

> configureStore.js

```
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import {routerMiddleware} from "react-router-redux";
import {persistState} from "redux-devtools";
import createLogger from "redux-logger";
import DevTools from "../dev/DevTools";

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

const enhancer = (history) => 
    compose(
        // Middleware you want to use in development:
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)),
        // Required! Enable Redux DevTools with the monitors you chose
        DevTools.instrument(), 
        persistState(getDebugSessionKey())
    );


function getDebugSessionKey() {
    if(typeof window == "object") {
        // You can write custom logic here!
        // By default we try to read the key from ?debug_session=<key> in the address bar
        const matches = window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&#]+)\b/);
        return (matches && matches.length > 0)? matches[1] : null;
    }

    return;
}

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
    // Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer(history))

    if (module.hot) {
        module
            .hot
            .accept("../reducers", () => {
                const nextRootReducer = require("../reducers/index");
                store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
            });
    }

    return store;
}
```

**Server**

> server.js

```
import path from "path";
import { Server } from "http";
import Express from "express";
import React from "react";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { match, RouterContext } from "react-router";
import routes from "./src/routes/routes";
import NotFoundView from "./src/views/NotFoundView";
import configureStore from "./src/store/configureStore";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
// import { syncHistoryWithStore } from "react-router-redux";

// initialize the server and configure support for ejs templates
const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "./"));

// define the folder that will be used for static assets
app.use("/build", Express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

// // universal routing and rendering
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    const store = configureStore(browserHistory);

    match(
        { routes, location: req.url },
        (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
            // in case of error display the error message
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err.message);
            }

            // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
            if (redirectLocation) {
                return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
            }

            // generate the React markup for the current route
            let markup;
            if (renderProps) {
                // if the current route matched we have renderProps
                // markup = renderToString(<Provider store={preloadedState} {...renderProps}/>);
                markup = renderToString(
                    <Provider store={store} >
                        <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                    </Provider>
                );
            } else {
                // otherwise we can render a 404 page
                markup = renderToString(<NotFoundView />);
                res.status(404);
            }

            // render the index template with the embedded React markup
            const preloadedState = store.getState()
            return res.render("index", { markup, preloadedState });
        }
    );
});

// start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";
server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

I don't know if I'm initializing correctly my store on the server-side.
How do I know this? Because `renderProps` is always null and thereby it returns `NotFoundView`.

However I made some modifications since I understood that my routes were being initialized incorrectly.

This made me use my `configureStore(...)` (which I use on client-side and it's working) on the server-side.

Now I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError:Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

This error happens on `AuthenticatedComponent` in the following line:

```
this.props
    .dispatch(push(`/login?next=${redirectAfterLogin}`));
```

It's strange since this works on client-side and on server-side it just throws this error.

Any idea?

**PS**

Am I doing it correctly by using the same `Routes.js` in client and server?

And the same for my `configureStore(...)`?

All the examples I see, they use a different approach to create the server-side store, with `createStore` from `redux` and not their store configuration from client-side.

**PS2**

I now understand that `push` may not work on server, only client (right?). Is there any workaround for this?

**PS3**

The problem I was facing was happening because I was rendering `<Router />` into server, and my `routes.js` should only contain `<Route />` nodes.

However, after a while I discovered that history shouldn't be configured in server and I just configured my store and passed it to the `<Provider />` being rendered.

But now I need to compile my JSX and it throws:

```
Error: Module parse failed: D:\VS\Projects\Tests\OldDonkey\OldDonkey.UI\server.js Unexpected token (46:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                 // markup = renderToString(<Provider store={preloadedState} {...renderProps}/>);
|                 markup = renderToString(
|                     <Provider store={store} >
|                         <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
|                     </Provider>
```

Comment: There are some errors in the code but they don't match with the error you're getting. For example, you call `routes(store)` in `match`, but `routes` expect a `props` object. Inside `routes` you access `props.store`, `props.history` and those should be `undefined`. Is this the most recent version of the code?

Comment: I already changed the Code many times trying to resolve this. I call props.history only if store comes null or undefined, so I may pass only store

Comment: Can you update your question with the most recent version?

Comment: My current code is equal to this, since I didn't change it after posting on SO

Comment: My question is, am I doing it correctly by using the same `Routes.js` in client and server? And the same for my `configureStore(...)`? All the examples I see, they use a different approach to create the server-side store with `createStore` from `redux` and not their store configuration from client-side.

Comment: @Lucas, Ok I changed my code a bit and I passed the initial error, which was caused because I was rendering `<Router />` inside my routes. I followed your tip in your first comment.

Comment: @Lucas, but now I can't run my server.config and neither I can run the bundling through webpack to convert my server.config into ES5